# Why does rails crash trying to render a page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I did an update to my rail environment, and now it is crashing when it tries to render any page. This has not happened to me before, and I cannot find any similar questions posted here, so I'm posting this in hopes of a useful suggestion as to how to correct this, as I have no clue.

I'm using Rails 3.2.2, ruby 1.9.3p194, and rvm 1.14.1, on Debian Linux beta 2.6.32-5-686.

Today I upgraded Rails and ruby to these latest versions, using **gem pristine --all** and **bundle install**.

The rails server start ok (with a security warning about no "secret option" but I trust that is innocuous), but when any page is requested, it crashes, with the following last portion of the dump trace:
...

```
1030 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb
 1031 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb
 1032 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb
 1033 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb
 1034 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb
 1035 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb
 1036 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb
 1037 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb
 1038 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/will_paginate-3.0.3/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb
 1039 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb
 1040 /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb

* Process memory map:

08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:12 1074503381  /Net/delta/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 00:12 1074503381  /Net/delta/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
099b7000-0b76f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
```

...

```
which goes on for some time, then ends with:
b7582000-b7774000 r-xp 00000000 00:12 1611124550  /Net/delta/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/libruby.so.1.9.1
b7774000-b7778000 rw-p 001f1000 00:12 1611124550  /Net/delta/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/libruby.so.1.9.1
b7778000-b778a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b778a000-b778b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b778b000-b77a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 654765     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b77a6000-b77a7000 r--p 0001b000 08:02 654765     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b77a7000-b77a8000 rw-p 0001c000 08:02 654765     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
bf90a000-bf91f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
```

If anyone could point me in right direction to troubleshoot this, I'd appreciate it, as I'm rather baffled by this behavior...

--rixter

Comment: Not a solution, but Rails 3.2.2 is still relatively old, and has known bugs/security vulnerabilities. I doubt if any of them are the cause of your issue but its possible, and you should upgrade to 3.2.11 for the security fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be segfault with ruby 1.9.3. `openssl` might be culprit. Try changing the
`source` to `'http://rubygems.org'` in Gemfile.If it has some effect then re-install ruby with `--with-ssl-dir` option after fresh install of `openssl` as below:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm remove 1.9.3-p194
rvm install 1.9.3-p194 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Try if that works